# Tappable Highlight Color - Android

Tags: android, ionic2

Intending to remove the tappable highlight color in ionic2 hybrid app.
Was successfully able to do that for ios by the following link:
http://meshfields.de/ionic2-tappable-highlight-color/

But no luck with android, can someone help out with that.

Even tried setting

```
ion-item {
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

But neither this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link it suggests to do:

```
.item-ios {
    background:none;
}
```

For android use `md` prefix/suffix which is "material design" which is added by ionic for android.

```
.item-md{
        background:none;
}
```